# Get MAX Date while using SQL subquery with join

Tags: sql, date, join, subquery, max

I have two tables Deal and SCHNAV with a common field 'security'. Deal contains details of all securities purchased and sold till date and schnav contains closing security holding for each date. I want an sql to fetch the latest (max) date for all trades done in securities held as on a particular date only upto that date from deal table.

I used the following query to get all the deals and then from pivot got the latest value. But i need an sql so that I dont have to do mnipulation in Excel.

```
select scheme, security, asset_type, tran_type 
from deal 
where security in (select security from schnav where nav_date = '31 Mar 2013') 
  and d.value_date < '01 Apr 2013';
```

Please help. and Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the `deal` and `security` tables together.  In addition to the condition on the `security` field, you also have conditions on the date.

Finally, you need to find the last deal on or before the date.  Most databases support the `row_number()` function for this purpose.

The following query combines these together:

```
select scheme, security, asset_type, tran_type
from (select d.scheme, d.security, d.asset_type, d.tran_type,
             row_number() over (partition by d.security order by d.value_date desc) as seqnum 
      from deal d join
           schnav s
           on d.security = s.security and
              d.value_date <= s.nav_date and
              s.nav_date = '31 Mar 2013'
    ) d
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

To get only one `tran_type`, use a `where` clause in the subquery:

```
select scheme, security, asset_type, tran_type
from (select d.scheme, d.security, d.asset_type, d.tran_type,
             row_number() over (partition by d.security order by d.value_date desc) as seqnum 
      from deal d join
           schnav s
           on d.security = s.security and
              d.value_date <= s.nav_date and
              s.nav_date = '31 Mar 2013'
     where d.tran_type = 'P'
    ) d
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon , let me try this and check

Comment: Hi Gordon, what if i want to do it for a specific security and not for all the securities in schnav table

Comment: @user2630322 . . . You would add a `where` clause for that security, in the inner query.

Comment: hi gordon, the above query didnt return value_date (latest) column.

Comment: @user2630322 . . . It should be returning the lastest value date on or before 2013-03-31.  Isn't that what you want?

Comment: no the query wasnt returning any date. but i tweaked it and it worked.

Comment: select scheme, security, asset_type, tran_type, value_date from (select d.scheme, d.security, d.asset_type, d.tran_type, d.value_date, row_number() over (partition by d.security, d.scheme order by d.value_date desc) as seqnum from deal d join schnav s on d.security = s.security and d.scheme = s.scheme and d.value_date <= s.nav_date and  s.nav_date = '31 Mar 2013') d where seqnum = 1

Comment: one more thing gordon. If there are two tran_type 'P' (for purchase) and 'S' ( for sale) then if I want the sql to check only for 'P' then how to tweak it